# How to verify that email from own server to google relay SMTP service is using TLS

Tags: email, postfix

I have a server which only sends mail out, as follows:

`django/python --> postfix  ----->  smtp-relay.gmail.com  ----->  destination`

When I open a gmail client that received the email, and check the details it says: `security:    Standard encryption (TLS) Learn more`

Now I suspect its saying from `smtp-relay.gmail.com` --> gmail destination was TLS, but I am concerned I am sending email in plain text from postfix to `smtp-relay.gmail.com`.

My postfix configuration file has:
`relayhost = smtp-relay.gmail.com:587`

However if I set it to:
`relayhost = smtp-relay.gmail.com:25`

It also works.

[This is the tutorial I followed](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-as-a-send-only-smtp-server-on-ubuntu-18-04)

If I set django settings to `EMAIL_USE_TLS = True` and try to send an email, it fails with:

```
 File "/usr/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 755, in starttls
    raise SMTPNotSupportedError(
smtplib.SMTPNotSupportedError: STARTTLS extension not supported by server.
```

This makes me think its not using TLS, but I don't know how to verify.

Comment: Depending on your log settings, you may see the negotiation and cert verification for the transaction.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to look at the `Received:` header of your mail as it was received, the line where Google traces your message being transmitted from your Postfix server to the first Google server. That header should specify the protocol as ESMTP**S** - the (second) **S** signalling a secure channel.

There will be another `Received:` header where your Postfix server notes the receipt of the message from django/python, but if that submission is guaranteed to never leave your machine (connection from `::1` to `::1`), it should be of little concern whether that connection employed any transport security.

It is customary to have such trace headers additionally contain information about specific protocol versions and ciphers used (Google appears to do that most of the time).

If you know your mail server is not supposed to send out mail unencrypted - because you *exclusively* send mail to modern providers, or you are relaying *all* your mail to Google - consider enforcing that via `smtp_tls_security_level` in your postfix configuration. Looking at one message only tells you that in this particular instance, everything worked. You may not want it to silently fallback to unencrypted submission in the future.

Comment: Thank you for that insight. I do indeed see 'ESMTPS' now, whereas before it was just `ESMTP`. It appears django fails when setting TLS because then the talking from django to localserver is TLS, and it fails.

Comment: You can also add `smtp_tls_loglevel = 1` to your postfix configuration to log TLS connections, including version & cipher.